# Changing the voice used on Nexus 7 for Google Now search

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, 4.1-jelly-bean, nexus-7, search, text-to-speech

I have recently bought a Nexus 7 from the Google Play UK store and it seems to be configured as a US tablet in that the voice on the Google Now search is an american woman, whereas on my Nexus S when I search the voice that responds is a man's which I prefer for this purpose, mainly due to the accent the woman has. Is it possible to change the voice that the tablet responds with? I'd prefer solutions that didn't require rooting.

I've already tried changing the language to English (UK).

Comment: Have you tried changing the entire device's system language to English (UK)? Or just the voice dialect into English UK?

Comment: "I am with a few others: the bloody thing quit working after the Android sys update was installed. My playstore shows the app installed successfully, and I've un-installed both the tts and the uk tts and tried the "free" trial etc to no avail. Support after the sale? Ha!! I've followed the sage advise of other posters and I am at a loss. The bloody default voice continues to speak." from another user posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

There's a separate section to choose the text-to-speech output speaker:

Goto settings and choose the UK voice:
Setting => Language & input => Text-to-speech output => Google Text-to-speech => Language

You can install german, spanish, french, italian voice data additionaly to the preinstalled english US/UK voices.

Comment: I've since got the UK voice working but that was 2 weeks ago or so, I can't remember exactly what I did, I may have downloaded some UK English pack for something and brute forced a load of settings.. The point is now when I change the system language the voice search changes to the corresponding one, i.e. System language UK means voice UK, system US means voice US, which definitely wasn't the behaviour when I first got it. The option you're suggesting doesn't seem to change anything. Which is odd...

Comment: That's indeed strange. Did you update to 4.1.1 in between? Google TTS got a lot of fixes (it crashed silently and more from what I saw via Google searching). Side note: As far as I know, both UK + US voices are pre-installed

Comment: I didn't knowingly upgrade, usually for a system upgrade there's the 'Install Upgrade' dialogue and I don't recall one, however my version is 4.1.1.

Comment: Ok. I got my Nexus 7 10 days ago and instantly had to upgrade to 4.1.1, but that was only a matter of <5mins (quite smooth and user friendly OTA). Well, anyway, seems this is fixed then. Anything I can improve in my post above??

Comment: Does the TTS option change the voice on your tablet? If not guess it's a version difference so you could you add in the info about changing the whole system language changes the voice on 4.1.1 and the answer you gave presumably was the old way to do on 4.1.0..?

Comment: I did some tests using Osmand and system languages en-UK, en-AU, en-US: The TTS voice followed the setting in "Google TTS Engine", i.e. I could switch between the male UK and the female US voice. My system is  however not the original Google 4.1.1 but a CyanogenMod10/4.1.1 build.