# Changing the Google Now voice back to male?

Tags: text-to-speech, google-now

Not sure why, but today the voice on Google Now has changed from a male to a female. I'm in the UK and before I had a male with a British accent but now that's changed to an American female.

I can live it, although I would prefer to have the male one back. It sounded more human IMO. Anyone know how I can get it back?

I've tried changing the language setting but it didn't make any difference.

---

**EDIT:**
A while ago Google changed the voice to a female with a British accent and AFAIK there's no way to get the male British voice back. Not really a problem for me anymore as the new voice seems to have improved a lot.

Comment: Am sorry but I find this funny, are you running JB by any chance [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1784091), Look at the second posting referring to a zip file called *transgendered* which needs to be applied. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this question can be answered any more, because I have had the English UK male voice back for a while now. Turns out it was Google changing things - not me. Just one day it reverted back to the male voice. Thanks to the guys who answered though! :)

Answer (score 2):

I have Jelly Bean 4.1.1, and I was able to change the Text-to-speech output setting to **English (United Kingdom)**, which is a male voice. The setting is at `Settings | Language & input | Text-to-speech output | Preferred Engine | (settings icon) | Language`.

*However*, Google Now is still giving me output in the **English (United States)** (female) voice.

Changing the `Voice | Language` setting in Google Now to *any* flavor of English also had no effect.

I'm afraid that for the moment Google Now is only giving one option for English text-to-speech. (I'm in the U.S., so I can't *fully* test it, but what I've seen jives with what you posted.)

Comment: Is there a checkbox to say Always Use My Settings for the voice engine? The older Android OS had that, and if ICS/Jellybean has it, you can check it to force other apps to use your default.

Comment: @dymutaos: Nope. No such checkbox.

Comment: Aw, mine is already on "English (United Kingdom)". I can even play an example of it and it's a male voice although I'm not sure if it's the same. I think it sounds slightly different (more robotic than the Google Now male voice). It's weird that it suddenly changed on Google Now but hopefully it's only temporary.

Comment: I've had the same issue and posted a question about it: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27670/changing-the-voice-used-on-nexus-7-for-google-now-search However mine seemed to sort itself out after a while without me being entirely sure what caused it.

Comment: Guess I'll just have to wait then and see if it/he comes back. :) So yours has a male voice right now? My friend (also in the UK) is also having this problem so I assumed it was something Google did.

Comment: Okay, this is weird. Earlier (around 1-2pm ish) I got the male voice back but now it's gone again. Back to the woman. Suppose this proves it's Google's doing, right?

Answer (score 1):

`Settings -> Language and Input -> Text-to-speech output -> settings Gear for Google TTS -> Install Voice Data`. Then, click on US or UK for English voices, and download the Male voice!

Answer (score 0):

If you go to settings in Google Now and select voice> English UK, you get the male voice.

Answer (score -2):

The default Pico TTS engine on Android is only a female voice. Your phone probably came with a second voice engine that has a male voice, and it sounds like the voice engine somehow got switched from that to Pico.

To change it back (on 2.3 aka Gingerbread), open `Settings` -> `Voice input & output` -> `Text-to-speech settings`, and click on `Default Engine`. Change the default engine back to the other option. You can then `Listen to an example` to make sure it is set correctly.

ICS and Jellybean should have similar options to change the voice engine.

Comment: Google Now is not available on Gingerbread.